# this.template.querySelector(...).handleUpdateCase().then is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, promises

Hello,

I develop a parent LWC which calls a method from a child LWC.

Unfortunately, I get this error message:

> this.template.querySelector(...).handleUpdateCase().then is not a function

This is the parent LWC:

```
this.template.querySelector('c-ricba_-q-m_-send-s-m-s').handleUpdateCase()
            .then((data) => {
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                
            })
            .finally(() => {
                
            })
```

The child LWC (ricba_QM_SendSMS):

```
@api
handleUpdateCase() {
    console.log('Hello');
    return {
        ticketId: this.ticketId,
        message: this.message
    };
}
```

I would like to understand why the method "then" is not a function please (the child LWC is in the HTML file in the parent LWC)?
Maybe the error is from something else?
I know the child method is called because if I can read the "console.log" in the developer console of the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@api
handleUpdateCase() {
    return {
        ticketId: this.ticketId,
        message: this.message
    };
}
```

You didn't return a `Promise` or use `async`, so `then` isn't a function of the return value. As written, it's just a normal function, so you can write:

```
let result = this.template.querySelector('c-ricba_-q-m_-send-s-m-s').handleUpdateCase();
```

Comment: I understand, thank you.
A promise will be the result of a server-side call?

Comment: @Oupat Yes, like if you did `handleUpdateCase() { return myApexMethod(); }` you would have a Promise.